# Hardcoding a query in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have a following query where I need to put .(dot) with query result. The query is given below:

```
SQLQuery_get_Tables:='SELECT major +'.'+ minor +'.' + release + '.' + patch FROM ['+ DBPage.Values[1]+'].'+'[dbo].Release';
```

for example.

```
major = 5
minor = 6
release = 2
patch = 8
```

the query should return like

```
5.6.2.8
```

How to do so? I am getting an error from the above query.

Comment: Wait, why do you want to query DBMS for that if you know the result ?

Comment: The result is coming from the query which is fired in  a database

Comment: Aha, I see that now. Which DB do you use ?

Comment: You just have to double those quotes.

Comment: i have already put double quotes.but runtime error is coming

Comment: Not double quotes, double quotes. From `'` you must make `''`, not `"`.

Comment: Yes TLama, i have put the same

Comment: And the error you got is ? Please be precise.

Comment: 'SELECT major +' '.' '+ minor +' '.' ' + release + ' '.' ' + patch. Getting error from the above

Comment: The error is like 'syntax error'

Comment: this looks double quotes in stackoverflow editor. but i have put what you are suggesting

Comment: Could you please copy/paste the query that you really execute and what **exact error message** do you get ? We both save a lot of time... I doubt that what you're showing in your question at this time even compile, hence I've suggested to double your quotes. You've said you did but you get error. So I've asked you to be precise about the error and you said *syntax error*. Sorry, but it looks like you don't even want to help... :)

Comment: That was my last attempt to help you here... If you care more about your nick name here rather than giving a feedback, nor elaborating your problem, then I see that you're not serious in what you do. Good luck!